# How to set mat-checkbox as checked and unchecked using api response in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

I am new to angular 6, here I'm trying to set a mat-checkbox as checked and unchecked based on the API data.

but in my case it's not worked, almost I have tried all the way to change the state .but it not worked for me.

API Response :

```
{"Table":[{"BUY_NOW_STATUS":"false"},{"BUY_NOW_STATUS":"true"},{"BUY_NOW_STATUS":"false"},{"BUY_NOW_STATUS":"true"}]}
```

app.component.ts

assigning the response to the local variable as follows.

```
this.summary = data['Table'];
```

And I have checked whether I am getting data or not in the console and I got the response in the console as I expected.

aap.component.html

```
<div  *ngFor="let data of summary">
   <mat-checkbox [checked]="data.BUY_NOW_STATUS" class="mat-checkbox-inner-container">Buy now</mat-checkbox>
 </div>
```

currently, it shows as all the checkbox as checked.

can anyone help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> before assigning please check the datatype of your BUY_NOW_STATUS
>   coming from a server it should be boolean not string else convert the
>   datatype to boolean

you have to use `[(ngModel)]` for 2 way binding data in angular.

to make this applicable use `[(ngModel)]="data.BUY_NOW_STATUS"`

this will also help you to store the current value of your checkbox which is true or false

after using `[(ngModel)]` there is no use to use `[checked]`

Comment: it's also showing all the checkbox as checked state @Hrishikesh Kale

Comment: In your stackblitz link I can see a checkbox ,nothing else there @Hrishikesh Kale

Comment: check the datatype of your BUY_NOW_STATUS coming from a server it should be boolean not string else convert the datatype to boolean @Zhu

Comment: @Hrishikesh Kale I am not receiving any boolen response from server. Getting id only. How to handle it here?

Comment: @Priya what are those id's only 1 or 0 or something different, else you need to handle programmatically to handle this case assigning boolean values to your checkbox id's

Answer (score 0):

Use **ngModel** to set the values like below. And **'name**' property need to be set otherwise checkbox won't work properly..

```
<div  *ngFor="let data of summary; let i = index;">
   <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="data.BUY_NOW_STATUS" name="status{{i}}" class="mat-checkbox-inner-container">Buy now</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```